# Initialisation from incompatible pointer type warning. Can't find the issue

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, double-pointer

I'm assuming this warning is crashing my app. I'm using objective-c for an iOS app. Xcode doesn't give a stack trace or anything. Not helpful.

I have this assignment as a global variable:

```
int search_positions[4][6][2] = {{{0,-2},{0,1},{1,-1},{-1,-1},{1,0},{-1,0}}, //UP
    {{-2,0},{1,0},{-1,1},{-1,-1},{0,1},{0,-1}}, //LEFT
    {{0,2},{0,-1},{1,1},{-1,1},{1,0},{-1,0}}, //DOWN
    {{2,0},{-1,0},{1,1},{1,-1},{0,1},{0,-1}} //RIGHT 
};
```

Wouldn't search_positions therefore be a pointer to a pointer to an integer pointer?

Why does this give "Initialisation from incompatible pointer"?

```
int ** these_search_positions = search_positions[current_orientation];
```

Surely this just takes a pointer to an integer pointer from the array, offseted by current_orientation?

What I am missing here? I thought I knew pointers by now. :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`search_positions[current_orientation]` is not of type `int**`; it is of type `int[6][2]`.  `search_positions` is not a pointer; it is an array.

A pointer to `search_positions[current_orientation]`, would be of type `int(*)[6][2]` if you take the address of the array:

```
int (*these_search_positions)[6][2] = &search_positions[current_orientation];
```

or of type `int(*)[2]` if you don't take the address of the array and instead let the array-to-pointer conversion to take place:

```
int (*these_search_positions)[2] = search_positions[current_orientation];
```

Comment: Okay thank you. I think I remember now... It would be easier if arrays were just pointers. You can make arrays through pointers (Just think about malloc), why can't it be the other way around?

Comment: @Matthew Mitchell: Arrays _aren't_ just pointers. That's a fundamental fact of C. If you want them to be the same it would mean abandoning one or the other. Which would you prefer: no pointers or no arrays? I think doing without either would make for a severely crippled language.

Comment: Well you can have a pointer to an array (Not an array apparently. Maybe a set?) of further pointers or some data. You can do this with malloc. You can access data in these pointer arrays or whatever with the same square braket syntax. It makes it more confusing for me.

Comment: @Matthew:  Yes, the relationship between arrays and pointers is a bit confusing when first learning C.  Yes, it would be less confusing if arrays or pointers were defined differently.  However, C is what it is and we get to live with it :-)

Comment: It all makes sense now except the int (*these_search_positions)[2] syntax. Don't know how that defines a pointer to an array of 2 integers.

Comment: @Matthew:  You can interpret C declarations using [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Answer (score 1):

*Pointers are not arrays, arrays are not pointers*

`search_positions` is defined as an 'array of 4 arrays of 6 arrays of 2 `int`s'. This makes `search_positions[current_orientation]` an 'array of 6 arrays of 2 `int`s'.
This array can be implicitly converted to a pointer, but that would give you only a pointer to an array of 2 `int`s (`int (*)[2]`). This is a different type from the 'pointer to pointer to `int`' that you were using and there is no suitable conversion between the two.

To overcome the problem, you could declare `these_search_positions` as

```
int (*these_search_positions)[2] = search_positions[current_orientation];
```

Comment: Okay thank you. So I can convert the first level of the array to a pointer of integer arrays? I'll try to remember that and the syntax you posted which I can't make sense of.